# Use Facebook Access token via Android on Laravel Backend

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-access-token, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have a Android app which gets Access token from Facebook SDk and I further want to send that token to PHP-Laravel Backend and retrieve user details.

I made HttpPost call with param AccessToken accessToken.getToken() to Laravel and there I retrieve it, the token is same as when I try to login from Web interface and get Token.

Then I made call to
$user = Socialize::driver('facebook')->getUser($request->token);

// Manual Function added to AbstractProvider Class

```
public function getUser($token){
    $state = null;

    if ($this->usesState()) {
        $this->request->getSession()->set('state', $state = Str::random(40));
    }

    $user = $this->mapUserToObject($this->getUserByToken($token));
    return $user->setToken($token); 
}
```

But I get this error in my log

[2016-01-16 07:30:24] local.ERROR: exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?access_token=&appsecret_proof=/* proof here*/&fields=first_name,last_name,email,gender,verified` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthExce (truncated...)
' in C:\wamp\www\PayPanel\PayPanel\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:107

Comment: You need to update the composer